# How to implement stronger app signing keys

Tags: java, android

I was reading this blog post:

http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/09/09/psa-think-about-stronger-app-signing-keys.html

and seemingly for any new apps I should try to create a stronger signing key.

From the post:

> Switching to a larger keysize is not that hard… for new apps. Just
>   specify -keysize 4096 when creating your production signing key, and
>   you should be good for a long time, barring a major decryption
>   breakthrough for RSA signatures.

I have a brand new app... how would I go about adding a bigger keysize? Sorry if this is a noobish question, but I don't see keysize anywhere when I export my app. Thanks

Comment: You do not specify the keysize when you export the app; you specify the keysize when you create the signing keystore. See Litrik's answer.

Comment: You have to create a keystore in a terminal?

Comment: Yes. Leastways, I am not aware that Eclipse has a wizard for that.

Comment: I've always used the wizard in eclipse for this. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) explains how to generate a key. You can modify the  sample command to use a larger key size:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -validity 10000
```

Comment: I was under the impression that you could just generate a keystore from inside of eclipse. Do I simply type this command in a terminal to get a 4096 keystore?

Comment: Eclipse automatically generates a debug keystore for you. You can NOT use that keystore when you publish to the Play Store.

Comment: Just execute that command on the command line to generate a 4096 keystore.